# Style a EditText android

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

How to style a `EditText` like below image.
I tried different option but cant achieve that.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lan40.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/round_corner"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:hint="First Name *"
    android:textColorHint="#a9a9b3"
    android:textSize="18dp"
     />
</LinearLayout>
```

***then create a drawable file for the round corner background***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
<stroke android:width="2dip" android:color="#b0b6bc" />
<corners android:radius="3dip"/>
<padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" 
 android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYhV1.png)

Answer (score 1):

```
  <EditText
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:hint="   Name*"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>
```

***create a xml in drawble folder  add this in it***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
    <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#363534" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
</shape>
```